# Why Microsoft named its sp hive folder 12 ,14 and 15

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

This might not be good question to be asked here. But yesterday one interviewer asked me why Microsoft named its **SharePoint 2010 hive folder 14** not 13 as preceded **SharePoint 2007 hive folder was named 12**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hive folder indicates the major version number.

%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions##, where ## indicates the major SharePoint version

Reference 
https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/The-SharePoint-Hive

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint's internal version numbers apply to the internal version numbers of Microsofts Office Products. Version 13 is skipped for reasons of superstition (triskaidekaphobia, the aversion to the number 13). So indeed, Office/SharePoint 2007 is internally versioned 12, and Office/SharePoint 2010 is 14.

Comment: That's strange!!

Comment: Interesting answer. Is there any reliable source which mentions that.